# React-Native: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') at Server._symbolicate

Tags: javascript, react-native, metro-bundler

I am currently updating a react native app. Since it was not updated for a long time, I decided to create a new application with upgraded packages and copy my frontend and server code into the new Application.

However, after I start the Application, in the terminal where Metro runs, I get the following Errors...:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
at Server._symbolicate (C:...\app\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1067:38)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Server._processRequest (C:...\app\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:444:7)
BUNDLE  ./index.js

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
at Server._symbolicate (C:...\app\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1067:38)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Server._processRequest (C:...\app\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:444:7)

I cannot find in none of the code files I the usage of the property map except for:
`Promise.all(images.map(saveImage))`
where this line is not called that early in the code and Logs show that images is always an array.

and

```
RNFetchBlob.fs
            .ls(this._storagePath())
            .then(files => files.map(file => this._fromFileName(file)))
            .then(files => {
              if (callback) {
                callback(null, files);
              }
              resolve(files);
            })
```

However, the file including this code is not even imported into index.js.

Does anyone know how to handle such an error, since I don't want to mess around with the node_modules too much.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.9",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.9",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "10.6.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-exit-app": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-localize": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-markdown-view": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-simple-encryption": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "semver-compare": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.9",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.71.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I already tried to reset
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",

and tried to figure out why/when the error is occuring but since it does occure even before any code is executing I am not sure where to start.